# Send to messenger m.me link stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, webhooks

I had success using the following link to trigger a message from an itsalive.io facebook bot. It stopped working over the weekend.

```
<a class="send-to-messenger-btn" href="https://m.me/mypageid?ref=welcome"><img src="/img/messenger-icon.svg" alt="send to messenger"></a>
```

Why is this link no longer passing through the message on click to the facebook page?

Comment: What message? Do you actually mean the `ref` parameter, or what?

Comment: Yeah when I was using the same ref parameter before it was posting the message welcome and triggering a response from the bot. It's no longer doing this. Any idea why?

Comment: @CBroe All I want to do is pass through the message welcomecountdown through the m.me link is this possible through the ref parameter or does this have to be done another way?

Comment: You can not specify the message to send for the user. `ref` is only for your internal tracking purposes.

Comment: @CBroe so is there no way for the page to instantly pass the user a welcome message on click of the button? 

The bot I have currently (itsalive.io) works on a message triggering set responses.

For some reason when I had this page setup prior to going live this was working and I thought it was the ref element passing this trigger.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with the ref parameter - you're looking for the get started message/welcome screen, I think ... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/welcome-screen